# If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x) = f(2x)$, prove that $f(x)$ is constant

Tags: calculus, limits

If $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x) = f(2x)$, prove that $f(x)$ is constant.

Answer (score 5):

Assume there are $a,b$ such that $f(a)\neq f(b)$. What can you say about $f(a/2)$ and $f(b/2)$? How about $f(a/2^n)$ and $f(b/2^n)$? Can $f$ be continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: You could have done directly as $f(a) = f(a/2^{n})$ and by continuity this implies $f(a) = f(0)$. But working by contradiction is also fine. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Proving that $f$ is constant by assuming that $f(a)\neq f(b)$ is so standard, I didn't stop to think about it. But you're right.

Answer (score 3):

$\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(x)=f(2^{-n}x)= \lim_{n \to +\infty}f(2^{-n}x)=f(0)$

Answer (score 0):

**For context** this is quite related to the [scaling function of the system of Haar wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet), which fulfills:

$$\phi(t) = \phi(2t) + \phi(2t-1)$$

Wavelets and their scaling functions are defined in terms of scaled and translated versions of themselves. Both scaling function and wavelet for this Haar system become piecewise constant functions.